# How to format number 300 to 3.0 in php

Tags: php, numbers, format

I have a MySQL table which contains whole number.

```
Units
300,
900,
600,
125,
225,
```

I want it to display using PHP like thus

```
Units
3.0,
9.0,
6.0,
1.25,
2.25,
```

I have tried using number_format but doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is basic math:

```
echo $num * .01;
```

If you always want two decimal points:

```
echo number_format($num * .01, 2, '.', '');
```

If you want one decimal for x00 numbers just use make the third parameter a variable that is either 1 or 2 based on the last two digits of the original number or use the modulus operator to determine if the number is divisible by 100.

```
$round = ($num % 100) ? 2 : 1;
echo number_format($num * .01, $round, '.', '');
```

Comment: gotta go back to my basic math. hehe